# magic suggest returns POST 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2, magicsuggest

I'm trying to get autocomplete working in my rails application using Magic Suggest.

I think this is the correct question: How can I get MagicSuggest to grab the JSON that is at the URL I give it?

This is the error that console returns when I type letters:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/search_foods 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8706
Uncaught Could not reach server
```

Here's the magic suggest code:

```
 input.magicSuggest({
         data: "/foods/search/",
         placeholder: "Search Foods...",
         valueField:'idFood',
         displayField:'foodName'
       });
```

The Routes

```
resources :search_foods
```

The Controller and Action

```
class SearchFoodsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: %['Crack', 'Cocain', 'Gorilla Test', 'Horse Test']
  end
end
```

When I visit the /search_foods url directly I get

```
'Crack', 'Cocain', 'Gorilla Test', 'Horse Test'
```

as my code is designed to do.

I think the issue is in that MagicSuggest, by default, sends a POST request, although I'm not sure if that's entirely relevant:

```
You can pass the url from which the component will fetch its JSON data.Data will be fetched
         *     using a POST ajax request that will * include the entered text as 'query' parameter. The results
         *     fetched from the server can be:
         *     - an array of JSON objects (ex: [{id:...,name:...},{...}])
         *     - a string containing an array of JSON objects ready to be parsed (ex: "[{id:...,name:...},{...}]")
         *     - a JSON object whose data will be contained in the results property
         *      (ex: {results: [{id:...,name:...},{...}]
```

Comment: What is the significance of it? lol I wouldn't know otherwise. It's the default on my machine I suppose.

Comment: When you say you visit the url directly, are you implying that you type out http://localhost:3000/search_foods in a browser and you get the result?

Comment: Yup, When I type that exact url I get the result I expect.

Comment: Well.. This is the source view of the result. 'Crack', 'Cocain', 'Gorilla Test', 'Horse Test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicions about the POST request was correct.

My friend helped out so that's why I was able to fix this.

This is what I did..

1. Eliminated the FoodSearch Controller, because that's not needed at all.
2. Created a search action in my Food Controller like so:

   def search
     render json: ['cocain', 'crack', 'gorilla testosterone']
   end
3. Edited my routes to a POST request instead of a get *This was the key:

   resources :foods do
     collection do
       post :search
     end
   end

--- Another option, as  karlipoppins suggests, is to simply change the type of request that magicSuggest makes by including the method attribute like so:

```
        input.magicSuggest({
           method: 'get',
           data: "/foods/search/",
           placeholder: "Search Foods...",
           valueField:'idFood',
           displayField:'foodName'
        });
```

Then I wouldn't need to change the route to post.

1. Added this path to the data attribute in the js

   data: "/foods/search/"

This will be a huge help to anyone trying to get magicSuggest to work in rails. It's a pretty damn easy setup to be honest. That one bit and the JSON formatting was the only thing that was tripping me up here.

Comment: I'm glad you found your problem, but it had nothing to do with magicsuggest. Thus is just the standard way of outputting json from a rails controller and is used any time you perform any ajax stuff. Magicsuggest doesn't care how the format gets to it as long as it's properly formatted. You could have set the property `method` to `get` when creating the component if you wanted it to perform a get request instead of a post one.

Comment: Ah.. I see that. I was searching for a way to change the type of request magicSuggest was making to a get request. You just pointed out that I needed to look for the 'method' property.. I don't know why I didn't look for a property with that name. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input.magicSuggest({
         data: "http://localhost:3000/search_foods",
         placeholder: "Search Foods...",
         valueField:'idFood',
         displayField:'foodName'
});
```

Comment: POST http:// localhost:3000/search_foods 404 (Not Found)    without the space (SO is removing the http:// part)

Comment: please check if your server/controller code has a mapping to handle POST call to http:// localhost:3000/search_foods. Also your response is not in JSON format as required by MagicSuggest.

Comment: Ok. Please give me a little bit of time to figure out exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The doc states that the component expects one of the following:

```
     *     - an array of JSON objects (ex: [{id:...,name:...},{...}])
     *     - a string containing an array of JSON objects ready to be parsed (ex: "[{id:...,name:...},{...}]")
     *     - a JSON object whose data will be contained in the results property
     *      (ex: {results: [{id:...,name:...},{...}]
```

When you visit `/search_foods` you get

```
'Crack', 'Cocain', 'Gorilla Test', 'Horse Test'
```

This does not fit any of the 3 supported cases.